# Detecting Handlers of a jQuery "Live" Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, live, handler

Using:

```
$('#foo').data('events').click
```

We are able to access an iterative object of click handlers added to the element '#foo' but only when they were added with .bind()

Is there a way to get the handlers for an event added with .live()?

Is there any other way to know if an element has a click handler assigned?

Comment: Use your own customized event handler, you can do it in jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`live` events are added to the document. Use

```
$(document).data('events').click
```

The above will return an array of objects containing information about each bound click handler. Each of these objects has a `selector` property containing the selector that was used at the time of binding with `$(selector).live(.., ..)`.

Any of these selectors that matches the element with id foo will get triggered when `#foo` is clicked. Note that the selector does not have to be exactly `#foo` for that to happen. There are many other selectors that can be used to target an element. For example if `#foo` was a `<p>`, then a live click handler such as

```
$("p").live("click", function..)
```

will also target `#foo`.

Here's one approach. Loop through each object, and see if any of the elements matching the `selector` property include `#foo`.

```
var handlers = $(document).data('events').click;

// jQuery quirk: $.map callback takes arguments (obj, index) and
// $(..).map takes callback arguments as (index, obj)
var fooClickHandlers = $.map(handlers, function(handler) {
    if($(handler.selector).is('#foo')) {
        return handler;
    }
    return null;
});

// fooClickHandlers is a list of all handlers that will fire on #foo click
```

Comment: Great, but how do we know which of those handlers will fire when '#foo' is clicked?

Thank you.